# Posts on SE, -6 and no answer. Posts on Reddit, 15 upvotes and a relevant, interesting answer

Tags: discussion

Just for your information

http://www.reddit.com/r/skeptic/comments/1eivvw/does_royal_jelly_actually_have_human_health/ca0o19x

Now let the downvoting begin. I don't care.

Comment: The discussion here became a bit too personal, I've removed all comments. I'll ask everyone here to refrain from attacking each other.

Comment: I understand how frustrating it can be to ask a question and get no responses, but... I gotta be honest: if two pubmed links are what you were really after, you could've just searched for "royal jelly" and saved yourself even more time and frustration.

Comment: @shog9: do you really think I could not find the answer myself? I know how to search references. my purpose was different with that question, a purpose that apparently flew over the general understanding of the community.

Answer (score 4):

/r/sceptic and Sceptics.SE have different standards of posting. /r/sceptic has [rules](http://www.reddit.com/r/skeptic/wiki/rules), we have a [FAQ](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/faq) (a [rather more extensive one](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq), in fact).

Your posting on /r/sceptic complies with their rules. But it falls short *by a long way* of our standards here. In particular, we require a *well-defined*, *notable* claim (where the notability is *proved* in the question) to be tested.

Reddit allows a lot more chatty questions (and answers) and that’s fine but here on Sceptics.SE we have – as a community – decided on a much stricter set of rules to *remove* chattiness and focus on high-quality questions and answers.

Nothing of this should be new to you. Yet instead of complying (which, in the case of your question, would be rather easy since there are tons of references for notable claims about the effects of royal jelly) you insult the users as “twats”. Be honest with yourself: did you make an effort to act in good faith or did you want to stir trouble?

You know better than that.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, [this is the question this is about (10k-only link)](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16273/does-royal-jelly-actually-have-human-health-benefits). The reason why it was downvoted was likely because it had no notable claim, but insulting the users here probably didn't help either. The question also was not closed, even though a moderator saw it and commented on it, I assume because it looked like it would be easy to show notability. Your attitude in the comments likely provoked more downvotes than the question would have gotten without those.

We have the policy about notability for a reason, and it really would not have been hard for you to follow it in this case. Quoting a single sentence from the book you were just reading would have been enough. If you're not willing to spent that tiny bit of effort, then Reddit might be the better place for you.

The notability rule sometimes gets in the way, and I was not a fan of it in the beginning, but I see it as necessary to ensure the quality of this site.

Comment: I very much agree with this. I was SO pissed of at Sklivvz when I was new here, that he deleted my stuff, but then I realized reason for why he did that. Without references, without some formal 'crap', you risk turning into Yahoo answer where a huge chunk of all answers is simply not true at all. And that comes from someone that HATES formalities, and all forms of bureaucracy.

Comment: It makes no sense at all, because what I was asking was _not_ relative to the specific claims the book made. I asked if there was validated research on royal jelly, something that can be provided and it was in fact provided by an apparently less snobbish community. I don't give a damn about the claims the book made, and in fact I removed that soon afterwards, given how much focus was given to something irrelevant.

Comment: @StefanoBorini, Then, what you were asking was off-topic for this site, and we acknowledge that more questions are on-topic at reddit than are on-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

ROFL. Parting shots during rage-quits are often hilarious - they make me sit up and see if we can learn anything useful, and then they turn out to be so weak.

First, you are cherry picking. Rather than looking at your favourite answer, let's have a look at [all of the answers](http://www.reddit.com/r/skeptic/comments/1eivvw/does_royal_jelly_actually_have_human_health/)! In particular, check out the top answer:

> One spoonful calms you down.
>   Two spoonfuls makes you sleep.
>   But take 3 spoonfuls and you'll go into a sleep so deep... You'll never wake up!

Are there many answers that bad here at Skeptics.SE? I frequently don't enjoy Reddit due to its low signal-to-noise ratio. This is no different.

Second, the answer you selected has one preliminary study of n=15. The other has an unclear sample. Neither mentioned the adverse side-effects, especially allergies. Both are for some random health metric that didn't match any claim you identified.

It isn't clear it answered your (unclear) question. If you are changing your consumption of Royal Jelly based on these results, you are too easily lead.

Comment: "It isn't clear it answered your (unclear) question". it did, it provided me some material on published research. The validity of this research might be  debatable and can be a matter of discussion, but at least it's a starting point to enrich further. Also, the person answering clearly stated it's debatable. When it comes to signal-noise ratio, I don't care about the crappy answers, as long as I can get a decent one with the information I asked, that is, if there's validated research on royal jelly, something that apparently exists, although with debatable sample sizes.

Comment: @Stefano: Fantastic. If signal:noise ratio isn't a concern, and you just want articles on royal jelly, here are [another 55,000](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=royal+jelly) of them. Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is exemplified by the other answers you got on reddit:

> It has a pleasant taste. I also like bee pollen as a crunchy, slightly malty topping on ice cream and the like.

http://www.reddit.com/r/skeptic/comments/1eivvw/does_royal_jelly_actually_have_human_health/ca0owcs

> I know it turned my nasty spider bite into a normal wound, which then healed normally. I have some left over just in case I get another spider bite.

http://www.reddit.com/r/skeptic/comments/1eivvw/does_royal_jelly_actually_have_human_health/ca0uodg

Neither of these makes the internet better, and actually they make it worse. This goes against what StackExchange stands for, and that's why your question was downvoted - it was so open as to allow these valid, yet unuseful answers.

Surely your question could be constructed better, for example detailing what you have tried, or what really puzzles you. We have entertained similar questions in the past but they were all a bit more researched:

- [Does drinking the urine of camels have medical benefits?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/does-drinking-the-urine-of-camels-have-medical-benefits)
- [Do medical clowns help patients?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/11034/do-medical-clowns-help-patients)
- [Is marijuana an effective medicine for any one of these medical conditions?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/is-marijuana-an-effective-medicine-for-any-one-of-these-medical-conditions)
- [Is Kefir an effective treatment for bowel disorders?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10294/is-kefir-an-effective-treatment-for-bowel-disorders)

The more specific your question, the better the answers. You only had one useful answer out of four on reddit.

Comment: `The more specific your question, the better the answers. You only had one useful answer out of four on reddit, as an example.` But at least I got one. You could have provided the same answer here that could have been expanded, instead of slapping it at -6.

Comment: @StefanoBorini I don't know why you got a -6. I would have simply closed the question until you fixed it. Regarding the "at least I got one" comment: there would be no guarantee of that! We strive to have a very good S/N ratio - what's the last time you saw a reddit page as result of a google query?

Comment: my aim, with that question, was exactly to present a question that a normal person would have written and asked on google, so that it could get to skeptics.SE and get a detailed answer on such a question (which I am perfectly able to answer myself, by the way). Apparently the community thinks this is not a priority, so pardon me for the effort, I live well even without coming up with ideas.